# what is $$ and $ in webdriver and how to use it in JS applications?

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, cucumber

as per webdriver docs
`With the` **$** `and` **$$** `functions WebdriverIO provides useful shortcuts which can also be chained in order to move deeper in the DOM tree without using complex xPath selectors.`

but here i am trying to write `cucumber` test for my reactjs with flowjs application using web driver and chai , 
i have a UI like this , i need to test all buttons existence with button text/value. here is the design 
[image]

this is what i have tried

```
const links = $$('.button').filter(function(link) {
  return link.isVisible();
});
const button1_value = links[0].getText();
const button2_value = links[1].getText();
expect(button1_value).to.equal('button1');
expect(button2_value).to.equal('button2');
```

but i am getting the following error with `$$` ,
[image]

is there any alternative to get the list of buttons and test .

do i have to import `$` and `$$` to use in `js` files.

Comment: Are you sure you have your WebdriverIO properly installed?

Answer (score 0):

got it ,we can use `$$` and `$` with `browser`

ex: `const links = await browser.$$(selector);`

but to get the content/value of the buttons ,i followed this.

```
const links = await browser.getText('.button');
expect(links[0]).to.equal('button1');
expect(links[1]).to.equal('button2');
```